# Compiler error when setting size to a struct type global variable

Tags: c++, string, struct

I am getting the compiler error:

```
scheduleA3.cpp:97:16: error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'Section'
Section section[jk[1]];
```

I have a structure:

```
struct Section
{ 
int places;
string cities;
};
```

and I declared my global variable after this statement as `Section section[jk[1]];`

The issue is that I cannot set a custom index length jk is an array that serves as a counter that is a global variable as well. If I set Section section[0] then everything compiles. Any idea on why the compiler is restricting the use of a custom index size? Appreciate all the help and let me know if i could help make my question less vague.

Comment: The compiler attempts to implement the language as defined in the C++ standard, and that standard does not allow automatic or static storage arrays with a size that is not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the size of an array at compile-time, you can use vectors instead:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Section> section(jk[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basing the size of a static array on a runtime value `jk[1]` is not possible, because global storage is allocated statically, before your program gets a chance to run. C++ requires that sizes of global arrays be compile-time constants.

The value of `jk[1]` can change throughout the lifetime of your program. The size of the array is set once, and it can never change. If you need to gave a globally-available structure that can be resized, use one of C++ collections, and populate it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

new Standard support , my compiler is gcc version 4.1.2 and can compile and run ok

Comment: That is a compiler extension. It is currently not standard C++.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your type `Section` is a non-POD (Plain Old Data) type.  If it was just as you show it above, your code would work, because current versions of the C standard *do* allow variable length arrays, while many C++ compilers implement variable length arrays as an extension.  (Note: when I wrote this originally, I thought you were talking about a variable length array in a *function*, not a global.  I don’t know that global VLAs will work anywhere unless the expression resolves to a constant, and even then you might be dependent on the compiler in some cases.)

POD or Plain Old Data types are essentially the built-in types, plus `struct`s and `class`es made with those types, as long as they don't have explicitly defined constructors (compiler-defined default constructors are fine) or `protected` or `private` non-`static` data members.  For C++98, see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/4178176#4178176); C++11 changed the rules a little, so if you are using a compiler that supports that then you may also want to read [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821).

As has already been mentioned, if you have a non-POD type and want a variable-length array, you should use `std::vector` instead, e.g.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Section> section(jk[1]);
```

Note also that variable-length arrays declared with automatic storage (the default inside a function) will generally be allocated on the *stack*, whereas `std::vector` will use the *heap*.  Stack memory on some platforms is limited, and even when it isn't the stack has to be contiguous in memory (unlike the heap), which makes extended it difficult, so for larger arrays using `std::vector` is a better idea.

Comment: The current version of the C++ standard certainly *does not* allow variable length arrays. IIRC, the next standard will.

Comment: @juanchopanza You mean, it doesn’t allow *global* variable length arrays, right?

Comment: No, I mean it doesn't allow variable length arrays, period.

Comment: @juanchopanza Really? Seems surprising; they’re in C99---are they really not in C++11?

Comment: Yes, really. *Really* really. But as I mentioned, they may be in the next standard, hopefully out later this year.